# CakePHP : Paginator sort in view in select field

Tags: sorting, cakephp, pagination

I want to sort the content in `view` by selecting from a drop-down list.

Sorting is possible to do in table element by

```
<tr>
                <th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('category_id') ?></th>
                <th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('subcategory_id') ?></th>
                <th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('product_code') ?></th>
            </tr>
```

But I want to have a drop-down select list. And on selecting option from list the data will be sorted.

```
<select>
  <option><?= $this->Paginator->sort('category_id') ?></option>
  <option><?= $this->Paginator->sort('subcategory_id') ?></option>
  <option><?= $this->Paginator->sort('product_code') ?></option>
</select>
```

Comment: You can do normal form, submit on change, and set sortable in your controller action by post data

Comment: I do not want to create a form. Only a list and with no submit button. Selecting list will sort accordingly

Comment: and there is no need to write cakephp3 tag in title, i see you do this on each question...

Comment: i said submit on change without additional button, i've never use sort pagination this way.

Comment: you can sort using select tag.you need to give id to select tag and use jquery/ajax to sorting that data.